# How to read and Serial.print the contents (current values) of an 8-bit register?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, print, registers

Currently I'm using:

```
  ADMUX = 0b01100000; //example
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    Serial.print(bitRead(ADMUX, i));
  }
```

This correctly prints:

```
  01100000
```

But is there a simpler way?

Before coming up with above for loop I tried using just:

```
Serial.println(ADMUX);       //converts to integers: 96
Serial.println(ADMUX, BIN);  //leaves out leading zeros: 1100000
Serial.write(ADMUX);         //converts to ASCII char: `
```

Anything else I don't know of?

Comment: Are you asking because you're trying to avoid writing a loop yourself, because you're wondering if it's possible to do with fewer moving parts (whether that's done in your code or someone else's), or are you asking because you're under the impression that without a built-in thing you'd need to write a loop each time you wanted to print a value this way?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking either ;)

Comment: Me being new to using timers and registers, and having done some reading and experimenting recently, I just want to know what is the preferred or most elegant way to do this. I couldn't find an answer here myself. So I tried above ways. Maybe there is something better. If there is I'd like to know it ;)

Comment: `itoa(n, buffer, 2)` is not part of C++, but available in  Arduino, and achieve the same as `Serial.println(num, BIN);`. It need to define the buffer like `char buffer[33]` before using, so it is not much simpler.

Comment: If you look how [print_number](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L203-L221) is defined which is called by all `Serial.print(number, base)`, and how [binary](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/binary.h) is defined in Arduino Core, there is really no simpler way. Just define your for..loop as a function `print_binary()` and use it if you need.

Comment: "better" (without qualification) and "preferred" are highly contextual and mostly opinion based, which something that questions get closed for on stackexchange.  So, if you have a way to make the question more specific or objectively answerable, it's probably a good idea to do that.

Comment: @timemage I did ask 'simpler'.

Comment: @hcheung itoa() followed by Serial.print still no leading zeros. So indeed the same. Thanks for your input. Happy with the for loop then for printing. And I guess for other purposes I shouldn't be bothered by the left out leading zeros, as I suppose they don't make a difference when reading or comparing anyway.

Comment: @Gaai i noticed. that's part of what prompted my original question. maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
#include <LibPrintf.h>
printf("%.8b", ADMUX); //prints: 0110000
```

The LibPrintf.h library is standard included on ESP boards.
%b stands for binary. .8 for 8 decimal places, which adds leading zero's to all truncated (binary) numbers.

It becomes *simpler if you wanted to print the variable name along with it like:

```
printf("ADMUX: %.8b", ADMUX);
```

Results in:

```
ADMUX: 01100000
```

*Simpler in the way it now only occupies a single line of code.

Comment: Where the question was tagged UNO and NANO the following may be worth knowing for anyone considering this route. A minimal test framework around code in question results in _Sketch uses **1542 bytes (4%)** of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes._  The same around the code in answer results in _Sketch uses **11456 bytes (35%)** of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes._

Comment: You're right of course. And answer is cheating anyway as it uses a complete library. You could achieve the same one liner with a simple function for multiple calls. But thought it worth a mention especially as the library is standard on esp boards, even though not tagged. Might be good knowledge for people looking to do it on those boards aswell.

Comment: Or just that the cost is sort of amortized (through not removed) by _more_ use of LibPrintf. I didn't think so much about whether or not it was cheating. Only that this can be particularly important to be aware of. Any implementation of printf is a beast. However, on a project of any serious size the avr-libc (or whatever) one has often already been paid for, so to speak, by having been used at least once in someone else's code, whether you like it or not.

Comment: So if any printf or the like is already been used elsewhere (taking up that costly memory space anyway), you might aswell use it for this? That what you mean? (had to look up amortized, learning everyday ;)

Comment: No, it is not that simple. This happens **per** `printf` implementation. The cost-per-call for any given individual `printf()` implementation _enormous_ when you use it _once_. So the worst case scenario is where you have one usage of avr-libc one and one usage of the libprintf one. Also, the author(s) [have documented](https://github.com/embeddedartistry/arduino-printf) how you can remove features to trim the library size. There's only so much more I can say about this relevant to your answer.